# Activate the approval workflow after integrating the supplier invoice

Tags: acumatica

It's possible to disactivate the approval workflow in the persist action and activate after integrating the supplier invoice (AP301000)

Version: Acumatica 2020R2

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be simple because it won't be just a code snippet, nor have I tested the suggestion provided.  I believe it to be theoretically sound, but it would take me a fair amount of time to attempt.  Proceed with caution...

The standard approval process leverages EPApprovalAutomation.

```
public EPApprovalAutomation<MyDAC,
    MyDAC.approved, MyDAC.rejected, MyDAC.hold, MySetupApproval> Approval;
```

You specify the fields to monitor/set for hold, approved, and rejected.  I believe you can add a new field that will be set true by default and then control what event "unchecks" that field.  You will need to add the boolean field and the business logic to set it to false at the appropriate time.

If you re-define the Approval view in your graph extension, then I believe it will override the base view so that you can use your field to trigger the approval process rather than the standard "hold" field.

```
public EPApprovalAutomation<MyDAC,
    MyDAC.approved, MyDAC.rejected, MyDACExt.myCustomHold, MySetupApproval> Approval;
```

This may also require updating Automation Steps or the new UI workflow to transition to different statuses based on your customer hold field.  This is the time consuming part as everything is geared around changes resulting from checking or unchecking the hold field in those places.